# Millennium Problem Tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Do we really need a [millennium-problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/millennium-problem) tag?

And if yes, what should go under such tags?

---

For example, I don't think either of the two questions (related to Navier-Stokes) currently tagged as such should belong to a millennium-problem tag even if the tag is useful. Those two questions concern elementary issues regarding the Navier-Stokes problem, which is rather distinct from the Well/Ill-posedness result that the Clay list explicitly asks for.

In the same token, I don't think an elementary question on Ricci flow should be tagged millennium-problem just because it is the high-powered machinery used in Perelman's proof of Poincare. And who knows how many questions we've already had on things tangentially related to the Riemann hypothesis, the B and S-D conjecture, or PvNP.

Comment: While we are at it, why on earth do we have the tags "Marching-Cube" and "Marching-Tetrahedron." Really?  I fail to see the use....

Comment: @Eric I _don't_ think "higher-category-theory" should be merged with "category-theory".

Comment: @Grigory:  Ahh I see.  I should of looked it up before commenting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think this tag is useful.

Comment: If Grigory gets a "Nice Answer" badge because of this answer, can we pretty please delete the tag?

Comment: @J.M. It is done.